# ES6 import - different output file (webpack, babel)

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I build bundle.js output from jsx files with webpack and babel.

I have different bundle.js file for those two imports:

```
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

...bundle.js is big, because contains other react bootstrap components like Glyphicon, Modal, Portal, etc.

```
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap/lib/Button';
```

...bundle.js contains Button and its dependencies

What I'm missing? I need bundle.js only with these components, that I use. Should I use always second import?

Thank You.

Comment: Only require what you need, yeah. https://github.com/rollup/rollup is supposed to solve that problem, but that only works if libraries are also written in ES6.

Comment: That's not so good, because many libraries are not in ES6. So simple solution is one component per file and importing concrete file. Thank You for answer.